# Why store salt length as 4 2 bit values like this?

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm going through some code we received from an external dev team and they copied/pasted some code that I find all over the place without any real explanation for it:

```
private byte[] GenerateSalt()
{
    // We don't have the length, yet.
    int saltLen = 0;

    // If min and max salt values are the same, it should not be random.
    if (minSaltLen == maxSaltLen)
        saltLen = minSaltLen;
    // Use random number generator to calculate salt length.
    else
        saltLen = GenerateRandomNumber(minSaltLen, maxSaltLen);

    Console.WriteLine("salt长度：" + saltLen);

    // Allocate byte array to hold our salt.
    byte[] salt = new byte[saltLen];

    // Populate salt with cryptographically strong bytes.
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    rng.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);

    // Split salt length (always one byte) into four two-bit pieces and
    // store these pieces in the first four bytes of the salt array.
    salt[0] = (byte)((salt[0] & 0xfc) | (saltLen & 0x03));
    salt[1] = (byte)((salt[1] & 0xf3) | (saltLen & 0x0c));
    salt[2] = (byte)((salt[2] & 0xcf) | (saltLen & 0x30));
    salt[3] = (byte)((salt[3] & 0x3f) | (saltLen & 0xc0));

    return salt;
}

private int GenerateRandomNumber(int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    // We will make up an integer seed from 4 bytes of this array.
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[4];

    // Generate 4 random bytes.
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);

    // Convert four random bytes into a positive integer value.
    int seed = ((randomBytes[0] & 0x7f) << 24) |
                (randomBytes[1] << 16) |
                (randomBytes[2] << 8) |
                (randomBytes[3]);

    // Now, this looks more like real randomization.
    Random random = new Random(seed);

    // Calculate a random number.
    return random.Next(minValue, maxValue + 1);
}
```

My question: why all the extra work splitting the salt into 4 2 bit pieces and such? Why not generate a random salt and add 1 byte for storing the length to the beginning? I'm no crypto expert, so I guess there's a reason behind the logic, but I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Were I doing this from scratch, I'd probably keep it simple:

```
static readonly Random rng = new Random();

private byte[] AddSalt(byte[] plainTextBytes)
{
    var saltLength = rng.Next(0,255);
    var saltBytes = new byte[saltLength];
    var csrng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider;
    csrng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);

    var buffer = new byte[saltLength + plainTextBytes.Length + 1];
    buffer[0] = (byte)saltLength;

    Array.Copy(saltBytes, 0, buffer, 1, saltBytes.Length);
    Array.Copy(plainTextBytes, 0, buffer, saltLength+2, plainTextBytes.Length);
    return buffer;
}
```

Having said that I'm not even sure why they're salting the plain text to encrypt in the first place. The salt is typically used for the key generation while the IV exists to obfuscate the first block of the cipher, no? There shouldn't be a need for a salt AND IV in the encryption step, unless I misunderstand something.

Comment: It looks like they're just spreading the length out over 4 bytes so it's more obscure. One more piece of the puzzle to make pattern recognition more difficult. Of course, if someone has access to the source code, it doesn't provide anything extra. But if all the attacker has is a bunch of final hashes, they'll have a harder time figuring out what the salt is.

Comment: Using `Random` is not secure, not even after seeding it from an actual secure random number generator. Without an additional check or comment in the code you can just *wait* for the `minSaltLen` to be smaller than 4. The use of `GetNonZeroBytes` is strange, just getting bytes should be enough. And finally there is really no reason to randomize the *size* of the salt, just generating a salt that is sufficiently large with random values should be enough; throwing away random bits to store the size is just weird. This has FAIL written all over it.

Comment: Oh and 4 bytes is too few for the seed. You don't need to assign zero to `saltLen`. The only code that is worse than the original code may be your own code though. You don't want to get 0 salt bytes, right?

Comment: @itsme86 Well, they will see that some bits of the salt are probably always set to zero. So they obscure it and then drop a dead give-away right after.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes My example was a tip-of-the-fingertips substitute for the original, not something I'd submit for production ready.  Yes, Random has issues and the salt could be a static size, etc. etc. The only real question I had was why the random salt size and the excessive manipulation of the size bits in the original sample.  The bigger question that remains unanswered is: why salt the data at all? That's what the IV is for. Salting the key is sufficient here, no?